# How to display table in column

Tags: html, css, html-table, yaxis

I would like ti know if there is some option to display data from table in Y axes

```
<table >
                   
     <tr>
       <th>Week</th>
       <th>Day</th>
       <th>Lecture</th>
       <th>Exercise</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Time Finished</th>
        {this.props.global_grades.map((data)=> data.students.map((student, index)=> <th key={index}>{student.first_name}</th> ))}
     </tr>
                        
<tr>
   {this.props.global_grades.map((data)=> data.lectures.map((lecture, index)=> <td key={index}>{lecture.week} </td>))}
</tr>

</table>
```

this code will display everything in row but for example I would need to display second row like a column
Data are comming from react reducer as json and I have to loop over it.
Do you have any ideas how I could do it?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the array and build a new one with take the value at swapped indices.

```js
var array = [ [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ], [ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ], [ 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ], [ 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ], [ 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 ]],
    result = array.reduce((r, a, i) =>
        (a.forEach((b, j) => (r[j] = r[j] || [])[i] = b), r), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

or You can transpose your "matrix" as follow

```
let arr = this.props.arr;
let transArr = arr[0].map( (_, c)  => arr.map(r => r[c]));
return transArr.map(rows => { ... })
```

Updated https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/85529/